# Bitrix Calendar: выбор даты только будни

Tags: битрикс, cms, calendar

В `Bitrix CMS` есть встроенный компонент `bx-calendar`. В этом календаре при выборе желаемой даты доставки можно выбрать как прошедшую дату, так и выходные (в которые, например, доставка не осуществляется).

Как ограничить выбор даты в этом компоненте?

[image: календарь]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При использовании `BX.calendar`, в метод передается js объект, вот туда можно передать в параметр `callback` функцию, и там сделать проверку какую тебе нужно, и если не подходит под условия, возвращать false и выводить ошибку.

Почитай тут https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/js_lib/data/calendar.php